# Insert After First Row

Tags: jquery

At the moment I have a relatively simple table that looks like this:

```
<table class="table table-striped" id="manifestItemsTable">
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <th></th>
            <th>PRO No.</th>
            <th>Origin / City</th>
            <th>Destination / City</th>
            <th>Due</th>
            <th>Transf?</th>
            <th></th>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

And I have the following code which is part of a much larger script, but have pared it down to the relevant section.

```
var $tr = $('<tr class="row alert-message">').append(
    $('<td>').html(proNumber),
    $('<td>').html(originName+' / '+originState),
    $('<td>').html(consigneeName+' / '+consigneeState),
    $('<td>').text(month+" "+day+", "+year),
    $('<td>').html('<input type="checkbox" class="batchCheckboxTransfer" name="batch[]" data-id="'+shipmentID+'" value="">')
).appendTo('#manifestItemsTable');
```

What I would like is to make this append right after the first row that was already set in the table above (with the 'th' inside). Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To achieve this you can use `insertAfter()` and provide the selector for the first `tr` in the table:

```js
$('button').click(function() {
  var $tr = $('<tr class="row alert-message">').append(
    $('<td>').html((new Date()).getTime()),
    $('<td>').html('oName/oState'),
    $('<td>').html('cName/cState'),
    $('<td>').text('mdy'),
    $('<td>').html('<input type="checkbox" class="batchCheckboxTransfer" name="batch[]" data-id="shipmentId" value="">')
  ).insertAfter('#manifestItemsTable tr:first');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<button>Append</button>

<table class="table table-striped" id="manifestItemsTable">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <th></th>
      <th>PRO No.</th>
      <th>Origin / City</th>
      <th>Destination / City</th>
      <th>Due</th>
      <th>Transf?</th>
      <th></th>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```